# Finding the non-value part of ArgumentException.Message

Tags: c#, exception

An `ArgumentException` with a non-trivial `ParamName` has a newline split `Message` whose final line describes its `ParamName`; for example, `new ArgumentException("Some error", "myParam").Message` is

```
Some error
Parameter name: myParam
```

Now, while using a library which we'll consider black box for now, and which produces `ArgumentException`s with very useful error messages, I find myself wanting to take those error messages, add some context to them, and eventually present the information to my user. In doing so, I want to get rid of the "Parameter name" part of the exception message as that tends to be useful only during development.

So the question is: How do I get rid of the line containing "Parameter name" in the most elegant way? The `ParamName` property of `ArgumentException` allows me to get the parameter name itself, but there appears to be no direct way to get a message that excludes the parameter name. One thing I could do would be to simply take all lines of `Message` except from the last one, but that only works insofar that `ParamName` is not `null`; I can check this explicitly, but at this point I'm performing a bunch of parsing to solve what seems like the kind of thing that would be a .NET one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following extension method solves the issue somewhat succinctly but not without manipulating `ex.Message` directly:

```
public static string GetError(this ArgumentException ex)
    => ex.ParamName == null ?
        ex.Message : ex.Message.Remove(ex.Message.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```